# How to make our list persistent, while navigating to different screens in flutter application?

Tags: flutter, navigation, persistence, bottomnavigationview

In my flutter application, the bottom navigation bar is present and there are two bottom navigation bar items. I am using a List view on both of the screen. When I navigate from one screen to another after some scrolling on that screen. I came back at top of the list not at the last position where I had left. How can I do persistence on both screens?

Answer (score 1):

You can set keepScrollOffset to true..
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html

Comment: Yes i had already used scroll controller and by default the property keepScrollOffset is already true. Do you have any application example from github or others from where i can understand code that how things work. Thankyou

Comment: Please post an example app where you use the scroll controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PageStorage` and `PageBucket` for saving `ListView`'s scroll offset.

The working example is https://codepen.io/ntaoo/pen/LYpyrZJ .

The essential part is as below,

`final bucket = PageStorageBucket();
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: ListView(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>('0'),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Index 0: Home Start\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n to... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEnd',
              style: optionStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: ListView(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>('1'),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Index 1: Business Start\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n to... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEnd',
              style: optionStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: ListView(
          key: PageStorageKey<String>('2'),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Index 2: School Start\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n to... \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nEnd',
              style: optionStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ];`

`ScrollController` test code is a perfect usage example of `keepScrollOffset`'.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/scroll_controller_test.dart#L313

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PageStorageKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorageKey-class.html):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        key: new PageStorageKey('key_name'),
        itemBuilder: ...
    );
}
```